# No menu bar shown on the top panel after upgrading to 13.10

Tags: unity, menu, panel

Recently I upgrade my Ubuntu to 13.10 from 13.04, I just find the menu bar is not shown on the top panel. The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is also not working! Can anyone help me by guiding me to install some packages?

I fixed some other issues just by installing unity-scope-home, indicator-keyboard. So the upgrading ignored some necessary packages to be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo aptitude upgrade -y; sudo aptitude dist-upgrade -y; sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop -y;
```

This should pull all of them in for you.

Answer (score 2):

After other methods failed (unity-panel-service was not starting well), I was able to load the menu bar by placing a file menu_panel.desktop into ~/.config/autostart

menu_panel.desktop looks like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MenuBar
Comment=Start menu bar that fails automatically
Exec=/usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
```

Answer (score 0):

unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module
Install the above package will work for me.
The "apt-get upgrade" always miss out necessary packages.